# curl -v -H 'X-Storage-User: test:tester' -H 'X-Storage-Pass: testing' url:8080/auth/v1.0 results in "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Tags: openstack-swift

I have tried to setup SAIO - Swift All In One as per instructions in "http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html"

But when I execute "curl -v -H 'X-Storage-User: test:tester' -H 'X-Storage-Pass: testing' url:8080/auth/v1.0", it results in "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request".

I am new to Cloud Computing and hence any help in this matter is appreciated.

Comment: The request was malformed according to the server, i.e. did not respect the HTTP protocol completely. It is probably an issue with the headers. Run `curl` with `-v` and post the headers.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am executing curl with -v option. But in vain.

Comment: Opps I meant the -i option

Comment: Thanks, was able to retrieve tokens, but my subsequent GET fails with internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. My code "worked on my system", but when I tried to run my code against a Swift store hosted by Cleversafe, I got the same 400 error.

I solved the problem by using X-Auth-User and X-Auth-Key as the header names rather than X-Storage-User and X-Storage-Pass. Unfortunately, the Swift documentation is net very clear as to the distinction, if any, between these two options.